# Stop Slideshow function when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have a slideshow using background images in a div and am trying to stop it when a button is clicked.

```
function fadeTitles() {

$('#slideimg').addClass('flatironimg').fadeIn(500);
$('#slideimg').delay(4000).fadeOut(800, function () {
$('#slideimg').removeClass('flatironimg').addClass('kaynesimg').fadeIn(600);
$('#slideimg').delay(4000).fadeOut(800, function () {
$('#slideimg').removeClass('kaynesimg').addClass('chiassoimg').fadeIn(600);
$('#slideimg').delay(4000).fadeOut(800, function () {
$('#slideimg').removeClass('chiassoimg');
setTimeout('fadeTitles();', 0);
});
});
});

}


$('#slideimg').ready(function() {

fadeTitles();  
});
```

Here is the button info.(this works fine with out the auto advance slideshow)

```
$(function(){

    $('#flatironbtn').click(function(){
        if($('#slideimg').hasClass('kaynesimg'))
        {
           $('#slideimg').fadeOut( 600, function(){             $('#slideimg').removeClass('kaynesimg').addClass('flatironimg').fadeIn(600); });
        }
        else if($('#slideimg').hasClass('chiassoimg'))
        {
          $('#slideimg').fadeOut( 600, function(){              $('#slideimg').removeClass('chiassoimg').addClass('flatironimg').fadeIn(600); });
        }
        else 
        {
        }
    });   


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I recommend you find some tutorials on javascript before tackling jquery.  Completing some tutorials will help you write better code and understand how to frame your questions better when you do get stuck.

It looks like you've made 3 CSS classes with background image attributes - flatironimg, kaynesimg, and chiassoimg.  You have your site cycle the three images through the slideimg div automatically, but also want to give users a button to advance the slides manually.  Once the user has clicked the button, you no longer want the slide show to continue automatically.

I'm no jquery expert, but I can give you some code that should help you on your way.  I'll explain it bit by bit below- refactoring / contributions from more advanced users welcome.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var CLASS_ARRAY = ['flatironimg','kaynesimg','chiassoimg'];
  var slideIndex = -1;
  var automatic = true;

  function nextSlide(){
    $('#slideimg').fadeOut(600,function(){
      slideIndex ++;
      // Get the next highest item
      if(slideIndex >= CLASS_ARRAY.length){
      // If we run out of items, get the first one instead
        slideIndex = 0;
      }
      $('#slideimg').attr('class',CLASS_ARRAY[slideIndex]);
      // Swap out the old class attribute for the next one in our array
      $('#slideimg').fadeIn(600),setTimeout('autoAdvance()',2000);
      // Set the animation and have it autoadvance if appropriate
    });
  }

  function autoAdvance(){
    if(automatic) {
      nextSlide();
    }
  }

 $(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#flatironbtn').click(function(){
      automatic = false;
      nextSlide();
    });
    $('#resumebtn').click(function(){
      automatic = true;
      nextSlide();
    });
    nextSlide();

  });

</script>
```

Ok.  What are we doing here.  First I've moved the sequencing of your images out of the hardcoded jquery animation chain into an array.  This will help you change the order of your slideshow easily, add new styles without recoding, and keep your code readable.  I've also set an index to keep track of where we are in the list of classes, and a flag which tracks whether we should automatically advance the show.

```
  var CLASS_ARRAY = ['flatironimg','kaynesimg','chiassoimg'];
  var slideIndex = -1;
  var automatic = true;
```

Next I've defined a javascript function to handle the animation and load the next slide.  The function is a bit of reusable code that does one thing.  Now instead of chaining lots of animations together by hand, we'll write the code to animate the slide once and have it call the autoAdvance function to see if it should continue.

```
  function nextSlide(){
    $('#slideimg').fadeOut(600,function(){
      slideIndex ++;
      // Get the next highest item
      if(slideIndex >= CLASS_ARRAY.length){
      // If we run out of items, get the first one instead
        slideIndex = 0;
      }
      $('#slideimg').attr('class',CLASS_ARRAY[slideIndex]);
      // Swap out the old class attribute for the next one in our array
      $('#slideimg').fadeIn(600),setTimeout('autoAdvance()',2000);
      // Set the animation and have it autoadvance if appropriate
    });
  }
```

The autoAdvance function is very simple.  It checks to see if we are in auto-play mode.  If we are, it loads the next slide using the function above.

```
  function autoAdvance(){
    if(automatic) {
      nextSlide();
    }
  }
```

Finally, we set the javascript for our buttons to control the slide show, and kick off the first animation automatically:

```
  $(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#flatironbtn').click(function(){
      automatic = false;
      // Once the user has clicked, auto-play will turn off
      nextSlide();
    });
    $('#resumebtn').click(function(){
      automatic = true;
      // Give the user a resume button to pick up where they left off
      nextSlide();
    });
    nextSlide();

  });
```

Also, thanks to Chinmayee for cleaning up the format of your code.  It's always helpful to show people clearly what you're trying to do by indenting your code properly.